# How to get out of a method

Tags: c#, loops

I have a problem getting out of a method after the time runs out. I don't want to exit the whole program, but only this function during its execution. 
I need to get out of the method Check, not only the TimerTick.

I tried it with `return;`, `Enviroment.Exit(0);` that one closes everything, and with `goto` but I can't go to an identifier outside the void TimerTick like:

```
void TimerTick(Object obj, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Max time reached");
    goto Finished;
}
// some code
Finished:
Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
// end of the Void Check
```

However this is the current code what does not work like I want.

```
 public void Check()
 {   
     // 4 seconds
     Timer TimerOne = new Timer(4 * 1000);
     void TimerTick(Object obj, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Max time reached");
         TimerOne.Stop();
         // goto???
     }
     TimerOne.Elapsed += TimerTick;
     TimerOne.Start();
     // This for loop will go as long all items inside the list are entered
     for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
     {
         if (ListOne.Test.Contains(UserInput()))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
             points++;
             if (points == ListOne.Test.Capacity)
                 break;
             else
                 continue;
         }
         else
             Console.WriteLine("Wrong!");
     }
     TimerOne.Stop();
     Console.WriteLine("Stopped\n");
}
```

I hope it's clear to understand what I mean, I tried to sum everything up.

Comment: So you want to repeat X amount of times until correct, and also timeout after a certain amount of time? also this `points == ListOne.Test.Capacity` looks extremely suspicious, i think you need to research what `Capacity` is and does

Comment: @TheGeneral  I know what it does... but my Problem is: I want to end the void check after a certain time has been gone like 10 secs...

Comment: Your terminology `void check` is a little confusing, can you elaborate on what this actually means

Comment: What is the UserIinput method?  If it is a blocking method you can't exit until a keyboard key is pressed.  So you first have to make the keyboard entry an asynchronous method.  Then reorganize the code to handle the keyboard event.  Once this is accomplish it should be simple to exit when the timer expires using a Semaphore like a WaitHandle WaitOne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with your current code then you can do this:

```
public void Check()
{
    // 4 seconds
    Timer TimerOne = new Timer(4 * 1000);
    var expired = false;
    void TimerTick(Object obj, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Max time reached");
        TimerOne.Stop();
        expired = true;
    }
    TimerOne.Elapsed += TimerTick;
    TimerOne.Start();
    // This for loop will go as long all items inside the list are entered
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        if (expired)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (ListOne.Test.Contains(UserInput()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            points++;
            if (points == ListOne.Test.Capacity)
                break;
            else
                continue;
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!");
    }
    TimerOne.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Stopped\n");
}
```

Comment: That works fine! But I have another problem... when I haveit like its I am still able to add one addion Input, but I allready solved the problem that it countit to the points, however I am still not able to get rid of the remaining input. If I didnt explained it well here is the output:    Enter every name of the family! //Input  Enter every..., ..... 4 secounds areover.... // input and then comes the "Stopped"... how do I immedetly stop it?

Comment: @Dominik43566 - You can't. If the call to `UserInput()` happens before the `TimerTick` call then that's what you see. How can the program know that the timeout will occur before the user does their input?

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to allow only 4 seconds for answering the 99 questions and exit the function if it times out, you could check the time in the for-loop and break if the time has been exceeded.

This example uses a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to check the elapsed time:-

```
public void Check()
{
    var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 4000)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (ListOne.Test.Contains(UserInput()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            points++;

            if (points == ListOne.Test.Capacity)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Stopped\n");
}
```

(note, you could move or add a check to after the question depending on your requirements. You could also add a flag in the for loop so you could check afterwards if all the questions were answered before it exited)

A more elegant solution might be to use a `Task` with an absolute timeout:-

```
public void Check()
{
    var task = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            if (ListOne.Test.Contains(UserInput()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
                points++;

                if (points == ListOne.Test.Capacity)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong!");
            }
        }
    }

    // this will block for 4 seconds; if the task hasn't completed by then,
    // the task function will exit, and it will run the code in the if-block below

    if (!task.Wait(4000))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Max time reached");
    }
}
```